# How to access the first items in a list of arrays without for loop in Python 3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have an ode equation which produces a list like below:

```
u=[array([ 2.06642033, -0.03448756]), 
   array([ 2.03964994, -0.18737285]), 
   array([ 1.99884859, -0.21461016]), 
   array([ 1.95476809, -0.2254584 ]), 
   array([ 1.90875336, -0.23472173]), 
   array([ 1.86082857, -0.24471069]),
   ... ]
```

I want to plot `u[0]` and `u[1]` based on time. I try to access all first and second elements of u in two list with `l1=u[0:len(u)-1][0]` and `l2=u[0:len(u)-1][1]`, but it gives me only the first item from list. 
Does anyone have a solution for it?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "based on time"? Please provide some examples.

Comment: I have a time list which has the same length as u, like this: t=[0,0.001, ...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert your list of arrays into a single `numpy` array.

Also note that `numpy` array indexing in 2d is performed by `arr[row, column]`. If you don't filter by a dimension, just use `:`.

```
from numpy import array

u = [array([ 2.06642033, -0.03448756]), array([ 2.03964994, -0.18737285]),
     array([ 1.99884859, -0.21461016]), array([ 1.95476809, -0.2254584 ]),
     array([ 1.90875336, -0.23472173]), array([ 1.86082857, -0.24471069])]

u = np.array(u)

res = u[:, 0]

# array([ 2.06642033,  2.03964994,  1.99884859,  1.95476809,  1.90875336,
#         1.86082857])
```